# How to properly communicate with .exe file with python subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a .exe file that contains a lot of user-callable functions. Each function ends with writing to stdout, stderr or sends returncode. To get meaningful output from exe, it is important to run a sequential sublist of successful function calls.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("path\to\myfile.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

command = 'create myfile.txt\n'
process.stdin.write(command)
process.stdin.flush() 

# There should be some return value checking function

command = f' importToFile "{filename}" \n'
print(command)
process.stdin.write(command)
process.stdin.flush() 

#...all other necessary function calls... 

process.stdin.close()
```

Everything works, but code may have undefined behaviour, when trying to import to file, if it's creation has failed before. I can try to find potential errors with `err = process.stderr.readline()` but it just hangs, when there are no errors. Better solution seems to be `output, error = process.communicate()` , that gets even empty output values, but it closes my stdin, so that rest of my code is not executable anymore.

How can I see function return values properly without killing whole program?